# More than one TinyMCE (wp_editor) with different $settings['drag_drop_upload'] values breaks

Tags: tinymce, editor, visual-editor, wp-editor, plugin-tinymce

It appears that when I have two+ separate `wp_editors` with different values for `drag_drop_upload` they all are built as if they have `drag_drop_upload` set to true.

If I set them all to false they act as expected, but if they have different values they do not.

Here is code to demonstrate:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', function() {

    add_meta_box( 'asdf123_editors', 'Editors', function() {

        wp_editor( 'Drag/Drop => True', 'asdf123_editor_1', array(
            'drag_drop_upload' => true,
        ) );

        wp_editor( 'Drag/Drop => False', 'asdf123_editor_2', array(
            'drag_drop_upload' => false,
        ) );

    }, 'post' );

});
```

If you prefer, [here's the code as a gist](https://gist.github.com/matstars/1bb6c9efa1a5e27e3bec)

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a bug, but the behaviour is correct, or at least apparently intentional.

a) There is only one `dragDropUpload` setting in the tinyMCEPreInit object, instead of one flag per editor.

b) looking at `class-wp-editor.php:139`:

```
 if ( $set['drag_drop_upload'] ) {
    self::$drag_drop_upload = true;
 }
```

so, if the setting is set to true once, it is true and stays true. One way ticket to complete trueness.

Feels like a bug.
But even if this could be reset to false, it would be false for all editors then.
Doublebug?
Double chance for a mention in WordPress ~4.5 ;)

But to be fair: This is somehow bound to the media modal, and i guess setup is once on pageload..in other words, might be difficult to handle this on a per-editor basis. Codex/Docs should make this setting more clear.
Or maybe a global filter to turn this on/off would be more appropriate.